# CakePHP 3 integeration test without a model/entity

Tags: testing, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to test a controller function...
I want to test a couple of things:
A) That it throws an invalid request exception when a certain argument is used
B) That it works correctly when the correct argument is made.

I've written some unit tests and those all seem cool.  The only documentation I can find on this is http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html but the integration testing, whilst interesting and potentially useful, I can't seem to get how I am suppose to be implement it without using fixtures (which I don't want to do necessarily).

```
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Controller;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestCase;

class MusterControllerTest extends IntegrationTestCase

{

public function testIn()
{

    $this->in();
    $this->setExpectedException('Invalid request');
}
```

}

```
class MusterController extends AppController {

public $helpers = array('Address'); 

public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {

    $this->Auth->allow('in');
        $this->layout = 'blank';
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->loadComponent('Rule');       
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
}

public function in($param = null){

    if (!$this->request->is(array('post', 'put')) || $this->request->data('proc')!='yada' || is_null($param)){
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid request'));
    }

    $this->processRequest($this->request->data('hit'), $this->request->data('proc'), $param);

}
```

Pointers appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should explain the actual problem that you are facing. A fixture will not be required unless you query a table.

Answer (score 1):

The `IntegrationTestCase` class, as its name implies, is meant for integration testing. That is, it will be testing the interaction between the controller and any other class it uses for rendering a response.

There is another way of testing controller, which is more difficult to accomplish, but allows you to test controller methods in isolation:

```
public function testMyControllerMethod()
{
    $request = $this->getMock('Cake\Network\Request');
    $response = $this->getMock('Cake\Network\Response');
    $controller = new MyController($request, $response);
    $controller->startupProcess();

    // Add some assertions and expectations here
    // For example you could assing $controller->TableName to a mock class

    // Call the method you want to test
    $controller->myMethod('param1', 'param2');
}
```